# vtk SetFilePattern explanation

Tags: mfc, vtk

I have an vtkImageReader2 object ... but I can not figure ut how to use

```
    `vtkImageReader2::SetFilePrefix(...) `
```

and

```
    vtkImageReader2::SetFilePattern(...)
```

in order to have following path:

```
    D:\Tempx\PacientTest2\File00.dcm
    D:\Tempx\PacientTest2\File01.dcm
    D:\Tempx\PacientTest2\File02.dcm
    ...
    D:\Tempx\PacientTest2\File45.dcm
```

Can you help me, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correction

```
reader->SetFilePrefix("D:\\Tempx\\PacientTest2\\");
reader->SetFilePattern("%sFile%02d.dcm");
reader->SetDataExtent(0, 511, 0, 511, 0, 44);
reader->Update();
```

it is necessary to set the extent of the data on disk.
in this example i specify 45 images with 512x512 dimension.

tested with vtkImageReader2.

the function call GetFileNames() will not work in this case, different usage.

Comment: I don't mind if you explain me, why GetFileNames() didn't work in this case ... I struggled with that a lot of times ...

Comment: The method GetFileNames() only returns the vtkStringArray what you have previously specified by SetFileNames(). It does not return anything, if you have specified the data source in another way.

Comment: What if the image name indexing don't start from 0, but like 
Img_13.tif
Img_14.tif
.
.
how should the pattern be written in such case in SetFilePattern() ?